# Fitting a Yamaha DB50XG to a Korg NS5R?

Tags: synthesizer

I recently bought a second hand Korg NS5R, and was interested to find that it could originally be dealer-upgraded using a Yamaha DB51XG card (making it equivalent to an NX5R). Coincidentally, I have an old DB50XG card, which I believe is almost identical to the DB51XG.

Does anyone know whether the DB50XG would work in the NS5R?

I've been unable to find any documentation on fitting option boards (presumably because it was a dealer-fitted option). Before I remove the rather large number of screws in the case, any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: This appears to be a question about musical instrument maintenance, not sound design.  This unfortunately really doesn't fit here.

Comment: My apologies. I was concerned about this when I posted, but couldn't find a more appropriate Stack Exchange site. I could try to argue that it's possible to design sounds with a synthesizer, but that's a tenuous link!